# Task 'assembleFIRDebugEnabledDebug' not found in root project 'android'

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-analytics

When I run `flutter run --flavor FIRDebugEnabled`

I get the error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Task 'assembleFIRDebugEnabledDebug' not found in root project 'android'.
```

I also tried with `flutter run --flavor FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled`

But I get similar error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Task 'assembleFIRAnalyticsDebugEnabledDebug' not found in root project 'android'.
```

My goal is to use firebase analytics debug view https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/debugview

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: can you please try `flutter run -t lib/main.dart --flavor flavor_name --release -v`?
Thanks.

Comment: make sure you have followed all steps carefully. for more details https://cogitas.net/creating-flavors-of-a-flutter-app/